# Pass variable via intent into the onSensorChanged()

Tags: android, android-intent

I am writing a code for accelerometer which logs the data of accel values in background. I have an activity which will pass a string value that will be stored in background along with the accel values. I have passed them using intent and they are accessible in the onStartCommand() of that Service class. Now as I have written code for logging data in onSensorChanged() I need to pass that String to that onSensorChanged() function. How can I do that? I tried to create an intent on that onSensorChanged() function but that doesn't work !

Comment: onSensorChange is into the service or into the activity?

Comment: into the service class

Comment: I don't understand... haven't you passed "that string" to the service via the intent?

Comment: Yeah I have passed to that service via intent. But I can't access that in the function onSensorChanged() !!

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a private `String` field (a variable global to your service) and set its value into the `onCreate` method. Then, you can read its value from any other place into the service.